# Unix bash script for analyzing directory size

Tags: bash, function, shell, unix, directory

I am writing a simple bash script to determine the directory size. I know this is a very easy task by simply using `du -sh directory_name`.

I am trying to learn how to use for loops, while loops, if statements to accomplish this task. Here is my code:

```
    #while the directory size is less than 1
    while [ -d "$varDirectory" ] && $(du -sh $varDirectory) -lt "$minimumsize"
    do
        echo "$varDirectory is less than 1kb"
        exit
    done
    #for the directory, display the size in human readable format.
    for $varDirectory  
    do
        du -sh $varDirectory
    done

}
```

What it basically is suppose to do is check if the user input of the directory exists, if not then display it does not. Then use a while loop to check if the size is greater than 1 and display that it is greater than 1. Lastly, use the for loop to display the file size.

I get an error: syntax error near unexpected token `}'

**Update**

OUTPUT

```
    Please enter a directory
    /home/kayenine
    ./directory.sh: line 15: 298M: command not found
    ./directory.sh: line 20: 298M: command not found
    ./directory.sh: line 4: `$varDirectory': not a valid identifier
```

Comment: You should put this through https://www.shellcheck.net, but the specific error you have is probably because the last `for` loop doesn't have a `done`

Comment: You should also include a second check on `if [ ! -r "$varDirectory" ]` because a directory will test true regardless of whether you have permission to read from that directory. The second check to determine whether it is readable is prudent.

Comment: `du -sh` does not output a simple value like `298` it outputs `298M <dir name>` so you need get `du` to output plan old kbytes. So use `du -k $varDirectory | cut -f1` instead.  So the second part of your condition in your while loop should be `[ $(du -sh "$varDirectory") -gt "$minimumsize" ]`.  Note the `[]`'s.

Comment: How many times (more than the once required) do you call `du -sh $varDirectory`? Why do you use `while` multiple times when a simple `if.. then .. else .. fi` will do?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This statement is wrong:

```
while [ -d $varDirectory ] && du -s $varDirectory > $minimumsize
```

`>` redirects output.  It is not the greater than operator, `-gt`. This is causing your infinite loop.

This is wrong too:

```
    s=echo "$varDirectory is greater then 1kb"
```

You probably want to do this instead:

```
    s="$varDirectory is greater then 1kb"
```

This also has all sorts of problems:

```
while [ -d $varDirectory ] && du -s $varDirectory < $minimumsize
    echo $l
    l=echo "$varDirectory is less than 1kb"
```

For one there is no `do` or `done` so that's probably causing your syntax error.  Also `<` is redirection, not the less than operator, `-lt`.

I hope you don't run this script as root.

Update: Your update has problems too.

```
while [ -d $varDirectory ] && du -sh $varDirectory -gt $minimumsize
```

Should be:

```
while [ -d "$varDirectory" ] && [ $(du -k $varDirectory | cut -f1) -gt "$minimumsize" ]
```

I added the `""`'s per David's suggestion.

Comment: what do you mean there is no do?

Comment: Correct way is `while […]; do` you have `while […]; echo $l`.

Comment: Ok, so i have revised the code according to your comments and it seems to work, except i get this error after inputting a directory du: invalid option -- 'g'
Try 'du --help' for more information.

Comment: I did and it works for du -h but not du -sh. But when i check other stackoverflow answers i see that du -sh is a legit parameter.

Comment: if `$varDirectory` contains whitespace your `[ ... ]` will fail. (always quote within `[...]` or use `[[...]]`)

Comment: You were doing `while [ -d $varDirectory ] && du -sh $varDirectory -gt $minimumsize`. This makes `gt` arguments to `du`. You should do this instead: `while [ -d $varDirectory ] && $(du -sh $varDirectory) -gt "$minimumsize"`

Comment: @Kayenine `-sh` is valid, it is `--summarize` and `--human-readable` using *short-options*.

Comment: @RedCricket i appreciate your help so far. Just one thing I don't understand, it displays the size of the file but adds an error command not found on the lines where i added the while loop correction. I don't get why it would display correctly but add that piece of information

Comment: Why do this `for $varDirectory; do echo du -sh $varDirectory; exit 1; done`? Just do `du -sh $varDirectory`.

Comment: @RedCricket I made the correction but the error on line 15/20 the while statement displays line 15: file_size: command not found and does not display the greater then 1kb or less than 1kb

Comment: Why don't you post the output your script is producing as an update to your question.  I am not going to run your script so I can't see the output.

Comment: @RedCricket i updated the post with the updated code i'm using and the error.